# Webrick expected Hash (got Array) with jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm using the Handsontable jquery plugin to change cells in a datagrid.  Handsontable sends the data in an array as such:

```
var change = [['Z', null, 'X']]
```

I then pass this data to the server using ajax:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/incomes",
  dataType: "text",
  type: "POST",
  data: { data: change },
});
```

The problem is that with a null value ajax will ignore this value and change the array, like such:

```
change[0][0]    Z
change[0][1]    
change[0][2]    X
```

Because this value in the array is null, Webrick throws the following error:
    `Internal Server Error`
    `expected Hash (got Array) for param 0`

I'm really hoping to avoid looping through the data (there are multiple arrays in a real example) and changing any of these null values.  Is there an easier way to ensure that data can be sent to the server without erring out?

**HTML Error:**

## Internal Server Error

expected Hash (got Array) for param `0'

---

WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.9.3/2012-11-10) at
localhost:3000

**Terminal Error:**

```
ERROR TypeError: expected Hash (got Array) for param `0'
    /home/g/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rack-1.4.4/lib/rack/utils.rb:127:in `normalize_params'
    /home/g/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rack-1.4.4/lib/rack/utils.rb:128:in `normalize_params'
    /home/g/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rack-1.4.4/lib/rack/utils.rb:96:in `block in parse_nested_query'
    /home/g/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rack-1.4.4/lib/rack/utils.rb:93:in `each'
    /home/g/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rack-1.4.4/lib/rack/utils.rb:93:in `parse_nested_query'
    /home/g/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rack-1.4.4/lib/rack/request.rb:332:in `parse_query'
    /home/g/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rack-1.4.4/lib/rack/request.rb:209:in `POST'
    /home/g/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rack-1.4.4/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:26:in `method_override'
    /home/g/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rack-1.4.4/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:14:in `call'
    /home/g/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rack-1.4.4/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
    /home/g/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
    /home/g/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rack-1.4.4/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
    /home/g/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
    /home/g/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
    /home/g/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
    /home/g/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rack-1.4.4/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
    /home/g/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
    /home/g/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rack-1.4.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
    /home/g/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
    /home/g/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
    /home/g/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: Can you please post complete output from Webrick for this AJAX request? It would be especially helpful to see how Rails is interpreting your POST parameters.

Comment: Look at how jquery does params since you are basically using it to do all of the work for you http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/

Comment: @SebastianGoodman - I've uploaded the HTML error and the error I'm getting from the terminal thats running webrick.  Is there any other place to get the output?

Comment: @amchang87 - Thank you for the reference. I should expect something like `change[0][1]=&change[0][2]=X`, correct? So, I guess I don't know how Webrick is interpreting this?

Comment: I was really looking for the output from Webrick that prints something like "Started GET / with parameters {:data => [['Z', nil, 'X']]}". If the answer I posted below does not work, this information would be helpful.

Comment: @groc426 I would guess so, it's why it's strange. It could also by the way be the way you set up on your server ... now that Sebastian mentioned it. Make sure you set up the Rails server to accept JSON params etc.

Comment: @amchang87 - I've actually ran it on two separate local machines and both give the same results.  Maybe I'll try and push it out to Heroku just to see. I'll check on my settings too. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a stab in the dark, but you might try doing your POST with JSON or some other content type:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/incomes",
  dataType: "text",
  type: "POST",
  data: JSON.stringify({ data: change }),
  contentType: 'application/json'
});
```

I suggest this as a solution because the JSON format can represent null values and nested arrays more naturally (IMO) than the default x-www-form-urlencoded format.

**How this Works**

`JSON.stringify` will make sure your data are serialized as JSON. Using the `contentType` setting like this will cause the Content-Type header to 'application/json' in the HTTP request. Rails uses this as a clue to interpret the incoming POST body as JSON.

Comment: with this update, I'm getting an error: `MultiJson::DecodeError no object read at line 1, column 1 [load.c:1054]` What is posted looks like such: `data%5B0%5D%5B%5D=Z&data%5B0%5D%5B%5D=&data%5B0%5D%5B2%5D=X`  And I cannot find any other log info for webrick.  The above is all thats output, unless there is a log somewhere. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I forgot `JSON.stringify` when I wrote my answer. Try it now. About the log, I suspect your `Rails.logger.level` is not set to INFO or DEBUG. You can try adding this line to your `config/environments/development.rb`: `Rails.logger.level = :info`

Comment: You sir, have earned my humblest gratitude!! That works perfectly!  I have a learned a lot from your replies. Thank you very much!

Comment: It also worked for me, though, I can't understand what is happening. Previously I was doing some serious use of `$.ajax` + Rails with not problem whatsoever. The problem began once I started sending files through JavaScript. What's interesting is that the only thing that I changed based on this answer was the `dataType` and the `ContentType` properties. This is my previous call: http://pastebin.com/RryYDuE0